# displaying multi related data in yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app

[image]Am creating a management system using yii2.
Am trying to display data of many to one relationship but returns an error of not set as shown

Tables:

```
Case table
Columns: ref_no (primary key),case_description,case_raised_on

Evidence table
Columns: ref_no(foreign key), path, evidence_type
```

A case can have several evidences and each evidence belongs to a single case

```
RELATIONSHIPS IN THE MODELS:

Case Model:

 public function getEvidences()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Evidence::className(), ['case_ref' => 'ref_no']);
}



Evidence model
public function getEvidenceType()
{
    return $this->hasOne(EvidenceType::className(), ['type' => 'evidence_type']);
}
```

The controller

```
Case controller
public function actionView($id)
{
return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
]);
}
```

In the view file

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'ref_no',
            'case_description',
            'raised_on',
            'status',
            'updated_on',
        'evidences.evidence_type',                           
        ],
    ]) ?>
```

The view file returns an error of not set on the (evidences.evidence_type).It should display the record of all the evidence related to a certain case as referenced by the ref_no2

Comment: I don't understand the error.  Can yo please show the exact error reported ...

Comment: #Scais the error is actually it does not provide the records of the evidence model related to the case model. Instead it displays not set as the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using [DetailView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-detailview.html) Widget of yii2 and it takes only one model. So if you want to get a value from relation you have to call that relation in attribute array:

```
[
'label' => 'Evidences',
'value' => implode(',',\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($model->evidences, 'id', 'evidence_type')),
],
```

`$model->evidences` is your relation which you have declared in `Case Model`

Comment: If it works for you than you can mark it as a correct answer my friend :)

Comment: Okay and what if I want to display he records not as a comma separeted list(eg andy,kari, john)  but  as a block list moving down(eg 1.andy 2.kari 3.John)

Comment: You need to pass string to the `value`  attribute, before GridView object create variable with html markup through loop using `$model->evidences` relation then pass that string to `value` attribute simple.

Comment: can you give an example please

Answer (score 3):

You are doing it wrong way since Case Has many Evidences ..
One option is you have to implode array with `,`

try,,

```
<?php
$evidences  = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::getColumn((\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::getColumn($model , 'evidences')) ,'evidence_type');
?>
<?= \yii\widgets\DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'ref_no',
        'case_description',
        'raised_on',
        'status',
        'updated_on',
        [
            'label' => 'Evidences',
            'value' => implode(',' ,$evidences),
        ],
        'evidences.evidence_type',
    ],
]) ?>
```

Comment: After using the implode function I get ,,, . I have included a snapshot of the error in the question above